# C - Redirecting stdout after forking of child from parent

Tags: c, redirect, stdout

I'm writing a program to execute another program as a forked process and redirect it's output to a file or /dev/null on demand.

Currently I have forked and executed the external program using execvp().
Then redirected the stdout from a thread created before forking as the forked process will inherit parents file descriptor table allowing me to redirect after foking.

But, I can initially redirect stdout to a desired file and both parents and child's stdouts are being redirected. However if I try to redirect it again to another file, only parents stdout is redirected, child's stdout stays the same.

Here's the code without all the error checking bits.

```
struct params {
    const char *p;
    int fd;
    int wait;
};

#define EXIT_NOEXEC 126
#define EXIT_NOTFOUND   127
#define EXIT_MISC   127

static void dofile(struct params* st);
void dupit(const char *p, struct params* st);
void* reload_config(void* para);

int
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int exit_status, prog_status;
    struct params init;
    pid_t prog_pid;


    dofile(&init);

    prog_pid = fork();
    if (prog_pid == 0) {
        execvp(*argv, argv);
        exit_status = (errno == ENOENT) ? EXIT_NOTFOUND : EXIT_NOEXEC;
        err(exit_status, "%s", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else {
        while (wait(&prog_status) != prog_pid);
        return prog_status;
    }
}

static void dofile(struct params* st) {
    const char *p
    p = out.txt;
    dupit(p, st);

}


void dupit(const char *p, struct params* st) {
    pthread_t tid;
    st->wait = 0;
    int err = pthread_create(&(tid), NULL, &reload_config, st);
    if (err != 0) {
        printf("\ncan't create thread :[%s]", strerror(err));
        exit(1);
    } else {
        while (st->wait == 0) {
            sleep(1)
        }
    }
}

void* reload_config(void* para) {
    struct params *passed = (struct params *) para;
    int pre_config = 3; 
    int cur_config = 1; 
    int saved_stdout = dup(STDOUT_FILENO);
    char infile[5];
    int devNull = open("/dev/null", O_WRONLY);
    int file = open("out.txt", O_WRONLY);
    FILE *config;
    config = fopen("config.txt", "r");
    if (access("config.txt", F_OK) != -1) {
        while (1) {
            fgets(infile, 5, config);
            fclose(config);
            cur_config = infile[0] - '0';
            printf("output from thread, current config = %d\n", cur_config);
            if (pre_config != cur_config) {
                if (cur_config == 1) {
                    if (dup2(file, STDOUT_FILENO) == -1) {
                        err(EXIT_MISC, NULL);
                    }
                } else {
                    dup2(devNull, STDOUT_FILENO);
                }
                pre_config = cur_config;
            }
            if (passed->wait==0) {
                passed->wait = 1;
            }
            sleep(1);
        }
    } else {
        if (dup2(passed->fd, STDOUT_FILENO) == -1) {
            err(EXIT_MISC, NULL);
        }
    }
}
```

Well, I changed the code a bit so you guys will understand, so some parts will make no sense. But you get the basic idea.

How can I redirect child's stdout as I wish after forking.

Comment: AFAIK, a process can not directly change the streams of another process. The parent process will need to use an IPC mechanism to tell the child process what new file to redirect to and the child process itself needs to do the redirect.

Comment: But the initial redirection works, which means the child really inherited parents fd table. But whats unclear to me is, after the initial call, I can't redirect child's stdout.

Comment: That was *before* the fork. That is, there was only one process at that time. Once the fork is done there are then two processes that have the same file descriptors. But from that point on they are independent. That is, you can set up the file descriptors how you like before the fork and the child process once started will get those file descriptors - exactly as you have described. But there is no way for the parent to change the child file descriptors after the fork.

Comment: Thank you @kaylum you're correct. It was very helpful. A small illustration of mentioned IPC implementation would be golden right now :)

Comment: in some places in the posted code , the function: `err()` is be called.  In other places in the code there is the variable `err`  being used.   It is a very bad programming practice to have variable names the same as a system function.  Strongly suggest changing the variable `err` to a unique name

Comment: here is the prototype for the function: `execvp()`   `int execvp(const char *file, char *const argv[]);`   Notice that it has two parameters, not just one, and the second parameter is not optional

Comment: this line: `exit(0);` in the child part of the fork() results says everything was successful.  However, the execvp() failed, so everything was NOT successful. strongly suggest using: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: the code, right after the call to `fork()` is assuming that the call was successful,  However `fork()` can have 3 kinds of returned value  1) ==0 means child process  2) > 0 means parent process 3) < 0 means an error occurred.  The code is treating #3 as it the fork() were always successful.

Comment: regarding this line: `sleep(.2);`  here is the prototype for sleep(): ` unsigned int sleep(unsigned int seconds);`    Notice the parameter is a integer, not a float or double.  If you want your application to sleep for a fraction of a second, use: `nanosleep()`  here is the prototype for nanosleep(): `int nanosleep(const struct timespec *req, struct timespec *rem);`

Comment: the loop that contains this line: `config = fopen("config.txt", "r");` will open the file over and over and over and over .... the contents of the file will not change from one call to fopen() to the next call.  so, depending on the content of the first byte of the config.txt file, the while loop will execute either 0 or 1 times

Comment: the thread should be exited by calling: `pthread_exit( status )` and its' parent should be waiting (without burning huge amounts of CPU cycles) by calling `pthread_join()`  rather than that loop, looking for a change in a variable

Comment: I have corrected some issues pointer out. Sorry for if the code is unclear. Actually this is just a portion of the code that I have extracted from the real one just to explain the scenario. Thank you anyway for pointing these issues.

Comment: The loop that looks for a change in a variable as mentioned in  @user3629249's last comment is just to wait for one cycle of the thread loop. By calling pthread_join() will not escape the calling function and will not reach execvp() call

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked, here is a simple example. Some shortcuts have been taken for brevity but hopefully it gives you some idea. The program opens file1 and redirects stdout to that file. It then does a fork. The child process writes a counter to stdout (via `printf`) every 1 second. After a few seconds the parent process uses IPC, a `pipe` in this example, to tell the child to switch redirect file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{  
    pid_t pid;
    const char *file1 = "file1.txt";
    const char *file2 = "file2.txt";
    int pipefd[2];
    int fd;
    int rval;

    fd = open(file1, O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, S_IRWXU);
    if (fd == -1) {
        perror("file1 open");
        exit(-1);
    }

    /*
     * This pipe will be used by parent process to tell child which file
     * to redirect to.
     */
    rval = pipe2(pipefd, O_NONBLOCK);
    if (fd == -1) {
        perror("pipe");
        exit(-1);
    }

    /* Redirect stdout to the file opened before the fork. */
    dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO);

    pid = fork();

    if (pid == -1) {
        perror("fork");
        exit(-1);
    } else if (pid == 0) {
        /* Child process. */
        int ix;
        char redirect_file[100];

        close(pipefd[1]);

        for (ix = 0; ix < 10; ix++) {

            printf("%d\n", ix);
            sleep(1);

            rval = read(pipefd[0], redirect_file, sizeof(redirect_file));
            if (rval > 0) {
                /*
                 * Parent process has written a filename to the pipe.
                 */ 
                fd = open(redirect_file, O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, S_IRWXU);
                if (fd == -1) {
                    perror("file2 open");
                    exit(-1);
                }

                /* Ensure previous output has been written to current file. */
                fflush(stdout);

                /* Change redirect now. */
                dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO);
            }
        }
    } else {
        /* Parent process. */
        close(pipefd[0]);

        /* Wait a little and then tell child to change redirect file. */
        sleep(5);
        write(pipefd[1], file2, strlen(file2) + 1);

        wait();
    }
}
```

If this program is run you will find that half the child output went to file1 (first redirect) and other half of the output goes to file2 (second redirect).

```
$ cat file1.txt 
0
1
2
3
4
$ cat file2.txt 
5
6
7
8
9
```

One final note. The example program does the first `dup` before the `fork`. I did it like that because that's how your code was shown and also to emphasise the before and after `fork` aspect of the issue. But in real code the conventional way of doing that is to do `fork` first, then `dup` and finally `exec`. The `dup` is done after the `fork` so that only the child process gets affected and not the parent (unless that is really what you want).

Comment: Thank you @kaylum. Although this looks promising, after calling execvp() in forked process, I can't think of a way to keep a subroutine working. Even threading wont work.

Comment: "I can't think of a way to keep a subroutine working". Not sure what you mean by that. Do you mean a subroutine to do the `dup`? The new process needs to have that `dup` code written into it. If not then you are stuck. As already mentioned, a process cannot force another process to change streams without that other process's cooperation. Are you able to change the code for the new process that is `exec`ed?

Comment: I'm only saying that during execvp() call I will not be able to execute "/* Change redirect now. */ `dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO);`" that you've managed to do in a loop.